# Java asm compiler

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jvm, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I'm building a complier in Java using asm library. So far I can print to the output only integers.

I want to do the same thing with strings. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? You will need to modify each part of that code specific to integers, such as `INT_TYPE`, `ISTORE`, and `ILOAD`.

Answer (score 1):

Is it strictly necessary for you to emit the raw bytecode yourself?  If not, I have an API (see [here](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/overview)) that allows you to compose code using declarative expression trees, and then compile the expressions to bytecode (either as a callback for runtime invocation, or as a method body for a generated class).

The process of composing code with this API is considerably more natural and less verbose than  using ASM to emit raw instructions, e.g.:

```java
call(
    field(null, Types.System.getField("out")),
    "println",
    constant("twenty-two")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write the code in Java, compile it and ASMifier the code to see what it generates.

If you use IntelliJ and Eclipse you can do this in one step with the ASM Bytecode viewer.  I.e. you can have the sample Java code in one window, the ASM code which would generate it next to it.

See the ASM tab in both programs.  This will help you determine what ASM code to write to do something.

[image]

[image: Eclipse ASM plugin]

Comment: Reading the JVM spec is also a great way to learn about bytecode.

Comment: I will second that ... the wiki on the instruction list also served useful for me: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings